# Microsoft Word - Send to Mail Recipient - custom subject

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to override the native Send To Mail Recipient behavior in MS Word 2007/2010 to customize the subject of the email message. Is this possible? I can write the VBA macro to replicate the functionality, but is it possible override/customize the native behavior?
[image: Send To Mail Recipient]

Comment: I am confused, where is your code?

Comment: There is no code. I am asking if such customization is possible. The VBA could be something like http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/InterDev/SendMail.htm, but how can I override the Send To Mail Recipient behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to manipulate the hyperlink on email addresses in Word, the only thing you can preset it is the **Subject**.

Right click on the link in Word, click **Edit Hyperlink...**:
[image: Edit Hyperlink]

Then type in the customized email **Subject**:
[image: custom email subject]

Now with VBA, you can see the link is now including the subject. This means that you can use VBA to alter all the Hyperlinks.

```
?activedocument.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address
mailto:someone@there.com?subject=Customized%20Subject%20for%20the%20email
```

Note the spaces are now `%20`, so you may need another function to convert other non-alphabets.

Hope this is what your Native means.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't what I am referring to though. I'm added screenshot of this in Word 2010.